# How to store hierarchical data in groups (like Photoshop/Gimp layer manager)

Tags: c#, tree

I need to create a hierarchical way to group data in C#. Think of Photoshop or Gimp’s layer manager and you will understand what I’m trying to do. The data structure ideally should have the following features:

- Type safe implementation – no ‘object’ type
- Ability to put groups in any position of the tree
- Ability to iterate through the elements (not groups) simply without type checking

I already have a Tree structure which can store any data in a tree. The tree is made up of individual tree nodes which can store any children as well as the data. Then the tree supports enumeration as well as a lot of helper navigation functions.

My initial thinking was to create a generic ‘Group’ class that contains a list of items. Then populate an instance of my generic tree class with these groups. To visualize this in the UI it will appear as:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Group 1
  Item 3
  Item 4
  Group 2
    Item 5
```

However, internally only the groups are stored in the tree like this:

```
Default Group
  Group 1
    Group 2
```

Then, the items in each group are:

```
Default Group: Item 1, Item 2
Group 1: Item 3, Item 4
Group 2: Item 5
```

Then when I iterate through things I can do two foreach loops:

```
foreach (var group in tree)
  foreach (var item in group)
```

But this implementation has some issues: (1) Forces me to manage a default group (2) doesn’t allow me to arbitrarily put groups in any position (for example Group 2 between Item 3 and Item 4).

Anyone have any information for how this is normally or should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

```
   public class Group
    {
        public List<object> items { get; set; }
        public List<Group> children { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Well, it has the same functionality as my current idea (without the navigational benefits of using the Tree class I have). If I were to use this, I would definitely make Group a generic class too. The issue is that I can't position groups within the sequence of items. I would be stuck either putting all groups before or after items. This isn't how the layer managers work in Photoshop or Gimp.